# How to treat the parameters from C to x86 assembly

Tags: c, assembly, matrix, x86, intel

I'm doing an assembly x86 program that resolves the determinant of a 2x2 matrix. Well, i've done the *driver* in C and then I made a function that will be processed in the assembly x86 code.
That's the function in C: int det(int,int,int,int) **atribute**((_cdecl));
My question is: how do I take these four ints (that i passed like as parameters in that function) in x86? how can I operate with them in the x86 code?
I think that it could be with the stack, but I don't know how.

Comment: Oh sorry, I may have misunderstood your question. It seems you want to call assembly from C perhaps? Can you please clarify? If that is the case can you also show your assembly code? Are you trying to write inline assembly or standalone assembly - the answer will depend on which it is.

Comment: yes. that's it. here is the code.
the C code:

Comment: #include<stdio.h>

int det(int,int,int,int) __atribute__((_cdecl));

void main(void){
    int v[4],i;
    for(i=0;i<4;++i){
        printf("Ingrese valor para '%c':\t",97+i);
        scanf("%d",&v[i]);
    }
    printf("El determinante de la matriz ingresada es %d.\n",det(v[0],v[1],v[2],v[3]));
}

Comment: i'm from Argentina so the printf' text is in spanish

Comment: The duplicate is wrong. This is how to call Assembly functions from C.

Answer (score 0):

What you are basically asking is: where are the parameters located, right?

`cdecl` passes all arguments on the stack, in reverse order. Look up the specs of that calling convention.

So for your function:

```
int det(int p1, int p2, int p3, int p4);
```

Your stack will look like this at the beginning of your function:

```
p4
p3
p2
p1
return address
```

`esp` always points to the return address. `esp+4` points to `p1`, `esp+8` points to `p2` etc..

Please note:

As you are using the `cdecl` calling convention, you **must** preserve all registers, except `eax`, `ecx` and `edx`. When you execute `ret`, all other registers must be the same as they were when you entered the function.

The return value goes in `eax`.

Here's an example, using NASM syntax. Note that I didn't include a stack frame for the function, because it is a short leaf function, so it is a waste:

```
; UNTESTED
; int det(int a11, int a12, int a21, int a22)
_det:
    mov ecx, [esp + 4]
    mov edx, [esp + 12]
    imul ecx, edx
    mov eax, [esp + 8]
    mov edx, [esp + 16]
    imul eax, edx
    sub ecx, eax
    mov eax, ecx
    ret
```

Comment: thanks you! i can understand it. So, using the example that you've done with the stack, the last element of the stack will be p4?

Comment: @TikiQuaglia The stack doesn't have a "last element". It has a top. The fifth element from the top is `p4`. Beyond `p4` lies the caller's stack frame, which has local variables, it's own return address etc.

Comment: ohh ok. so if i continue passing things to the stack, they will be after p4 or before the return adress?

Comment: @TikiQuaglia if you push another element on the stack, it will be placed on top of the return address. But if you do, then the return address will be [esp+4] instead of [esp]. Note that before you return, you must pop all elements that you pushed, so that you leave the return address on top. You don't need to pop the parameters.

Comment: If you want to use the stack inside the function, it is best to create a stack frame.

Comment: ok. thanks you!. i didn't remember that the stack grows to downside. when i realize it everything make sense.